# How do i create a image displaying a email with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In my webapp i want to display user emails. But i dont want spam boots to steal my user emails. So have do i automatic create a image displaying there email?

Best regards,
A rails beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an image is one way to go, but remember that OCR is getting to be an extremely "cheap" operation and isn't a guarantee that a bot wouldn't analyze all the pictures on your site to see if they contain text that looks like email addresses. There's plenty of techniques to "hide" addresses in plain sight. Write them out in character entity format, intersperse empty tags, uses javascript to decode an encoded form of them and insert into the page after load, etc...

Comment: Can you give a example of how to hide email adresses?

Comment: `user<span style="display: none"></span>@example&x2E;com`. The span won't display, and the character entity will come out as `.`

Comment: How do i create this in a controller and displaying it in view?

Comment: Just some simple string manipulation. I don't know Ruby, but it can't be that hard to do a search and replace.